# Having 2 Entities connected thru a foreign key how do I get the Entities with no connection

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 entities Storage and Item. A Storage can have multiple Item, so I have a Foreign Key from Item to Storage.

By default to get the items in storage I use:

```
select * storage inner join item
on storage.id = item.storage_id
```

But how I get the Storage with no Items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS()` :

```
SELECT * 
FROM storage S
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                    FROM Item I 
                    WHERE S.id = I.storage_id
                  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `left join` if you want *all* storage values:

```
select *
from storage s left join
     item i
     on s.id = i.storage_id;
```